# VBA in For Each oItem Loop, how can i access the oItem's id?

Tags: vba, for-loop, foreach

I am going to write some code to illustrate the question.

```
For Each oElement in myArray
    MsgBox oElement
Next
```

This would print a message saying the value of "oElement" contained in "myArray" as many times as there is elements in "myArray".

However, what if i want to know the id of "oElement"? is there properties of "oElement" that i can access? something like printing the number of oelement instead of the value of the oelement?

```
For Each oElement in myArray
    MsgBox oElement.ID
Next
```

Is it possible? is there properties that can be accessed?

Thanks in advance for your time and attention,

Comment: You can run for each only over variants when its a array or against a collection. If its a pure array, there are no properties to access what to so ever.If interested in indexes, just loop from` lbound` to `ubound`. If its a collection, then you can access all the properties that the underlying object exposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to get the index of the item in the array. You have to maintain a separate variable:

```
Dim Index As Integer

Index = 0
For Each oElement In myArray
    Print Index
    Index = Index + 1
Next
```

Comment: totally agreed. Not to split the hair, but this way the `option base` setting also needs to be considered.

Comment: Thats how i solved it, but just wanted to make sure that there wasn't any undrlying properties that i could access to do it cleaner. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

a workaround could be the use of a `Dictionary` object instead of a `Variant` array:

```
Sub main()
    Dim myDict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim key As Variant

    Set myDict = GetDict '<--| get your "test" dictionary with "indexes" as 'keys' and "elements" as 'items' 

    For Each key In myDict.Keys '<--| iterate over keys (i.e. over your "indexes")
        MsgBox key '<--| this will give you the "index"
        MsgBox myDict(key) '<--| this will give you the "element"
    Next key
End Sub
```

where it's used the following function to return a "test" dictionary

```
Function GetDict() As Scripting.Dictionary
   'function to return a test dictionary

    Dim i As Long
    Dim myDict As New Scripting.Dictionary

    For i = 1 To 10
        myDict.Add i, "string-" & CStr(i) '<--| use the 'key' as your "index" and the 'item' as your element
    Next i
    Set GetDict = myDict
End Function
```

In truth, the following *reverse* approach could seem more similar to your initial code:

```
Sub main()
    Dim myDict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim oElement As Variant

    Set myDict = GetDict2 '<--| get your "test" dictionary with "elements" as 'keys' and "indexes" as 'items' 

    For Each oElement In myDict.Keys '<--| iterate over dictionary keys (i.e. over your "elements")
        MsgBox myDict(oElement) '<--| this will give you the "index"
        MsgBox oElement '<--| this will give you the "element"
    Next oElement
End Sub
```

where the following function is used:

```
Function GetDict2() As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim i As Long
    Dim myDict As New Scripting.Dictionary

    For i = 1 To 10
        myDict.Add "string-" & CStr(i), i '<--| use the 'key' as your "element" and the 'item' as your key
    Next i
    Set GetDict2 = myDict
End Function
```

but it'd have the major drawback of using your "elements" as `keys`, thus possibly violating their *uniqueness*, while sequential integers would always comply this requirement

Comment: I agree that this approach is exactly what my mind was looking for. The drawback is like you said, on one side the uniqueness and on the other side (for the sake of simplicity) it is easier to add a manual counter (like in previous answer) just to save time and lines of code.